# How to keep selected date after form submission?

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using `ng-bootstrap` date picker to my form. I need to keep selected date picker value after form submission. Currently date picker values empty (reset) after form submission. How to keep selected date picker values?

```
<form class="form-inline" name="form" #invoiceheaderform="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="invoiceheaderform.form.valid && save();">
```

From Date *

```
    <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control ngbfield" 
           name="invfromdate"  [readonly]="true" #vl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.fromDate" ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary fa fa-calendar" (click)="d1.toggle()" type="button"></button>
    </div>
    <!-- <div *ngIf="invoiceheaderform.submitted && vl.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">From Date is required</div> -->
  </div>

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="disableRunButton" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 expad">Save</button>

</form>
```

Comment: What is your save code doing?

Comment: please share `save()` function as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check whether you are modifying your model values (`model.fromDate`) in the `save()` function. Since it is a date, it is possible that you are changing the date format within the `save()` function and assign back to the same variable. If it is the case, use another variable to store modified values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control ngbfield" name="fromDate"  [readonly]="true" #vl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.fromDate" ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker">
<div class="input-group-append">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary fa fa-calendar" (click)="d1.toggle()" type="button"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: name of name attribute and ngModel was different. name="fromDate" [(ngModel)]="model.fromDate"

Comment: i changed it. but still date picker values clear after form submission

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the model values are reset on submit and since the values are bound by ngModel the date values are also reset

For submit, instead of calling save directly as above, consider passing the event as save($event) and calling event.preventDefault() from inside the save function